# Wordpress Server sending bad request to itself and crashing apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, cpanel, whm

Our Wordpress server has been choking itself. seemingly randomly, for the last 4 or 5 months. After a long process of troubleshooting various things I finally pinpointed it to 4-6 requests that show up in Apache. They're completely empty and they come from our own wordpress server IP. No VHost specified, no request path either. [image: Apache Status]

These requests get stuck in Reading Request, and any subsequent legitimate requests get stuck in Sending Reply until the scoreboard is full. The site effectively goes down until we restart FPM and Apache.

I "fixed" this by banning our server's IP from making requests via htaccess. Our apache now stays up but we get error logs for access denied to 400.shtml (bad request). This works, but of course I really want to figure out what is causing these requests.

I've checked our cron jobs and removed all of the ones from old plugins but the requests still come in anywhere from every hour to every 3 hours. This doesn't match any of the remaining cron frequencies.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm at wits end.

Environment details:

Dedicated WHM box, wordpress running on a dedicated IP as a sub account.

- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.2 with Zen OpCache
- nginx reverse proxy (Engintron WHM plugin)
- Cloudflare CDN.
- No other wordpress cache plugins except for cloudflare.
- No load balancers.

Comment: I'm having an extremely similar issue - apache gets clogged with connections stuck in "sending reply" for a wordpress site, for requests looking at various URL's. Using cloudflare too. Except in my case the IP's are anything, not the server IP specifically. I've had this on and off for months with no solution.

Comment: @ZhouW Are you using NGINX? Check your site's error logs for errors coming from your own server IP.

In my case, it was that a bot was submitting requests and including "#", which normally is a on-page link that doesn't get sent to a server. NGINX can't seem to handle it. I resolved mine by adding cloudflare rules that reject anything with the "#" in the request URI (which is always a bad request)